# sed rename files moving numbers to end of file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a directory that contains several files with the following pattern.

1953-MADAMA BUTTERFLY

1953-MADAMA BUTTERFLY_001

I'm trying to bath rename them to achieve the following:

MADAMA BUTTERFLY[1953]

MADAMA BUTTERFLY_001[1953]

This would mean remove the "-" and enclose the year between Square Brackets.
Since there are more numbers than the year I think the command should match only numbers with four digits.

I've reading trough sed documentation and didn't find any solution to my problem. Is it possible to achieve my goal with sed?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in pure bash:

```
for f in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-*; do
  mv "$f" "${f:5}[${f:0:4}]"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

To rename all the files in a directory, use

```
ls -1|sed -r 's/^([0-9]{4})(-)(.*)$/mv "&" "\3[\1]"/g'|sh
```

tested with `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

Using extended regular expressions (`-r`):

```
sed -rn -e 's/^([0-9]{4})-(.*)$/\2[\1]/p' /tmp/input_file
```

Or the same without extended regular expressions (added some backslashes):

```
sed -n -e 's/^\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(.*\)$/\2[\1]/p' /tmp/input_file
```

In both cases, the most important thing is to to match any digit (`[0-9]`) exactly 4 times `{4}`. We want to ensure that there is nothing before those digits, that's why use `^` which is beginning of a line and nothing after them, that's why we add `-`. You can change `-` to something like `[^0-9]` which means anything but a digit, if it's possible that there will character other than `-` or just drop this if digits there are also acceptable.

You may also use `?` if needed, making for example first group of digits optional and just printing filename without any changes if there is no match.